# connection between two computers through a server

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, centos-7, vps

I need to connect to a computer beyond the internet(or NAT) through my linux VPS. i have already installed an agent on the destination system and it would connect's it to a port on the VPS. now i need to forward that port to the port that i'm gonna connect to, with my system.

how to connect two ports together like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) does

Comment: Do you need to know exactly how port forwarding works in Linux or do you need to know exactly how to forward a port in Linux. These are two different questions: The first one is definitely off-topic here because it is too broad and is unlikely to be able to be effectively answered. It's also probably not what you're asking. The second one is more likely to be what you're actually asking, and so I ask you to use the EDIT button to clarify precisely what you are asking.

Comment: Port Forwarding won't cover any of that, it got nothing to do with VPS anyway. You need to set up a VPN, use software like OpenVPN, tinc, or if you want to go the easy way just use NeoRouter.

Comment: @Havenard you mean i should put them both in the same network?

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi That's what the VPN solution does, it creates a virtual network adapter on the devices that makes it looks like they are plugged together like in a LAN with all the traffic wrapped in cryptography as strong  as you want. The first two solutions allow you to make a very safe set up of client/server certificates, they may be annoying to configure though. NeoRouter on the other hand will get everything working in 10 minutes, but security is done with simple login/password pairs.

Comment: @Havenard i dont think its a good solution for simple works like an ssh connection or http connection like ngrok!

Comment: @Havenard yes it could be like that but i'm having a vps centos 7 and trying to make direct connect to another computer through it.

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi Sounds like VPN to me, you are just trying to do it the hard way (using SSH instead of a proper solution).

Comment: @Havenard i'm trying to make something like ngrok and surely he is not using VPN!

Comment: In that case it's unclear what you are asking. You don't "connect two ports together", it makes no sense. Perhaps you should clarify what you have and what you are trying to achieve so we can propose a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80304/discussion-between-ebrahim-karimi-and-havenard).

Answer (score 0):

Normally the ports are usually automatically configured by the router (mine does anyway) but if not you need to do it manually. You can configure port forwarding in your router (if supported). You need to visit your router's gateway in your web browser (usually 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1) and there should be an option for port forwarding. Make sure port 22 is forwarded.